# Blender asset browser limitations

Tags: asset-browser, library

I work at a company and we use Blender for creating scenes. We want to use more than 3K assets with the asset browser, but it's becoming slow in high numbers. any solutions for companies to use extensive asset libraries?

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: It's not a fact just  a guess, but since Asset Browser is quite new in Blender, it would not be unreasonable to expect performance improvements in the future. There is certainly room for improvement, since faster ways of loading assets seem to exist. See: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/asset-browser-so-slowwww/19909